# Unused arguments error in R studio

Tags: r, variadic-functions

I get an error when I try to run this line of code:

```
nnetPred.model <- nnetPred(X, Y, step_size = 0.4,reg = 0.0002, h=50, niteration = 6000)
```

The error message is:

```
Error in nnetPred(X, Y, step_size = 0.4, reg = 2e-04, h = 50, niteration = 6000) : 
unused arguments (step_size = 0.4, reg = 2e-04, h = 50, niteration = 6000)
```

My code is as below:

```
nnetPred <- function(X, Y, para = list()){
  W <- para[[1]]
  b <- para[[2]]
  W2 <- para[[3]]
  b2 <- para[[4]]

  N <- nrow(X)
  hidden_layer <- pmax(0, X%*% W + matrix(rep(b,N), nrow = N, byrow = T)) 
  hidden_layer <- matrix(hidden_layer, nrow = N)
  scores <- hidden_layer%*%W2 + matrix(rep(b2,N), nrow = N, byrow = T) 
  predicted_class <- apply(scores, 1, which.max)

  return(predicted_class)  
}

nnetPred.model <- nnetPred(X, Y, step_size = 0.4,reg = 0.0002, h=50, niteration = 6000)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use variable arguments. In R, this means the ellipsis (`...`). This is how you would define the top of `nnetPred` to use variable arguments:

```
nnetPred <- function(X, Y, ...) {
  para <- list(...)
```

This will work in your case, but is not really the best way to define that function, because it looks like you have a finite number of parameters. Only when you have an unknown number of parameters should you use variable argument lists. I would recommend simply putting your parameters in the parameter list. You can rename them if you want to:

```
nnetPred <- function(X, Y, step_size, reg, h, niteration) {
  W <- step_size
  b <- reg
  W2 <- h
  b2 <- niteration
```

Comment: Thanks, defining the function as you told worked. But now I have another problem. I'm new in this subject and stuck in it. Now I get another error: Error in nrow(X) : object 'X' not found

Comment: Are the `X` and `Y` variables defined anywhere? They aren't in the code you show. I had assumed they were assigned somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
try <- emd(xt2, tt2, boundary="wave")
Error in emd(xt2, tt2, boundary = "wave") : 
  unused argument (boundary = "wave")
```